# Style of notifications on SE2-Metas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, stackexchange-2.0, design

I find the dark gray text on the black background very hard to read.  Is it just me or could the style be modified a bit?

[image: Notification]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an error -- I told Sam not to use the answer style for notification topbar. I'll send him this link as a reminder.

Comment: Public humiliation much? :)

Comment: the beatings will continue until morale improves